# User form button create sheet on different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to Excel so I hope this makes sense. The code below is creating a new sheet based off a template and renaming it once a button on a user form is clicked. I'm having trouble trying to make the sheet being created open in a different existing workbook with the hyperlink still working. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this? Anything helps, thanks.

```
If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern" Then
Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets("Template")
Set sh = ActiveSheet
' Do whatever you have to do with the new sheet
sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"
End If
```

Comment: `Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets("Template")` is telling it to put the sheet in the same workbook after the sheet "Template". Try `wb = Workbooks.Add` the use `Sheets("Template").Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)` to make it the first tab of the new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are copying the worksheet "Template" to the current workbook.

Try this and see how this works and let me know if you get an error.

```
If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern" Then
    ' create objects
    dim wbk_dest as Workbook
    dim wks_copy as Worksheet

    ' initialize objects
    set wbk_dest = Workbooks("Destination Workbook")

    ' copies template worksheet to destination workbook and places the 
    ' the worksheet in the first position; you can place it anywhere
    Worksheets("Template").Copy before:=wbk_dest.Worksheets(1)
    set wks_copy = wbk_dest.ActiveSheet

    ' Set sh = ActiveSheet

    ' Do whatever you have to do with the new sheet
    wks_copy.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + _
                    AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + _ 
                    AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"

    ' what is "ws"?  is that a different worksheet?  the below statement
    ' looks like you are using a hyperlink to the newly copied worksheet.
    ' is that what you want to do?  As long as "ws" is visible you should be
    ' ok with this line
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), _
                      Address:="", SubAddress:=wks_copy.Name & "!A1", _ 
                      TextToDisplay:="View"

    ' clear object
    set wks_copy = Nothing
    set wbk_dest = Nothing
End If
```

#### Tip

try to avoid using the function Sheets().  Sheets() can refer to a chart that is not embedded in a worksheet or embedded in a worksheet.  I use Worksheets().  It is more specific and limits the possibility for error.

Comment: Sub or function not defined. set wbk_dest = Workbook("Destination Workbook")

Comment: what is the name of the workbook you are trying to add the worksheet to?  Since I don't know the name of the workbook you are trying to add the copied worksheet to you need to replace "Destination Workbook" with the name of the workbook you copying the worksheet to.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, doesn't seem to work. Gives me the error listed above.

Comment: Sorry typo, should be Workbooks("Destination Workbook")

Comment: Subscript out of range error  set wbk_dest = Workbooks("Destination Workbook")

Comment: Interesting.  That means the destination workbook is not visible or in a different application; or the declaration of wbk_dest is not visible in the same method / subroutine.